# Typescript map collection

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this complex models which i am trying to map.

- I have an array of **Carts** containing id, name and etc
- I have a dictionary where key is a type and its value is the different products.

I have added an example of what the result should looks like at the bottom of page.

My attempt but got stuck on how to filter

```
carts.forEach(cart => {
    const productList = cart.products; //list of products

    Object.entries(content.data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
      const sizeList = values.map(x => x.sizeList); //list of size
      // i am stuck here
    });
  });
```

Comment: There are many questions like this on Stack Overflow...  It would be helpful if you could show what you've attempted and what research you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getCartsWithProductNames = (carts = [], content = {}) => {
  // create a Map with productId-sizeId as key, and size name as value
  const productSizeNameMap = 
    Object.values(content)
    .flat()
    .reduce((map, { productId, sizeList = [] }) => {
      sizeList.forEach(({ sizeId, name }) =>
        map.set(`${productId}-${sizeId}`, name)
      );
      return map;
    }, new Map);
  // return carts list with product items having names from productSizeNameMap
  return carts.map(({ cartId, cartName, products = [] }) => ({
    id: cartId,
    name: cartName,
    productItems: products.map(({ id, size, quantity, isVisible }) => ({
      id, quantity, isVisible, name: productSizeNameMap.get(`${id}-${size}`)
    }))
  }));
}

const 
  carts = [
    {
      cartId: 500,
      cartName: "Some name",
      products: [ { id: 1, size: 10, quantity: 1, isVisible: true }, { id: 2, size: 13, quantity: 10, isVisible: true } ]
    }
  ],
  content = {
    "Drinks": [
      { productId: 1, sizeList: [ { sizeId: 10, name: "100ml beer" }, { sizeId: 9, name: "200ml beer" } ]
      }
    ],
    "Food": [
      {
        productId: 2,
        sizeList: [ { sizeId: 12, name: "6 wings" }, { sizeId: 13, name: "12 wings" } ]
      }
    ]
};

console.log( getCartsWithProductNames(carts, content) );
```

Comment: wow that was quick thank you. I am using typescript and on the line .reduce((map, { productId, sizeList = [] }) it doesnt recognise this overload

Comment: You're welcome, what's the error you're facing and what types do you have?

Comment: For now i just copied your code to my editor and it states TS2769: No overload matches this call on the reduce method

Comment: Did you fill the types where needed? Try sending me a sandbox that I can debug

Comment: If you paste your code to VS Code you can see the error. Selecting Typescript as the language

Comment: This would solve your issue: ``Object.values<{productId:string, sizeList:Array<{sizeId:string, name:string}> }>(content)`` and ``.reduce<Map<string,string>>``

Comment: I advise to define types to all the elements at hand and use them instead